# Prove or disprove the logic statement about subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove:

> If $ A \nsubseteq  B \cap C$, then $A \nsubseteq B$ and $A \nsubseteq C$.

I think it is false statement, shown by this counterexample:

let $A=\{1,2,3\} , B=\{1,2,3\}$, and $C=\{4,5\}$,

so $ B \cap C=\emptyset$, but $ A \subseteq B$.

Is my counterexample correct?

Comment: Yes, your counterexample is correct.

Comment: Yes, it works as a counterexample

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to mention that $A\not\subseteq C$. What you need is to mention that $A\not\subseteq B\cap C$ but $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your counterexample proves the statement is false.